# Is this "superset existence" problem NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete, decision-problem

The "Superset Existence Problem":

Let there be a set $S$, and $x$ subsets of $S$. Does there exist a set of size $y < |S|$, which is a superset of at least $z$ of those subsets?

To me, this feels like it should be NP-complete (in $|S|$), since it seems intuitively related to covering problems and minimum $k$-union. But I'm not sure where to start with the reduction.

So: is this problem NP-complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NP complete.
It is trivially in $NP$ (a certificate is the collection of the $y$ selected subsets of $S$), and it is $NP$-hard since it is the decision version of the [Maximum Coverage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem).